# Cannot install Joomla or Wordpress components and plugins

Tags: linux, wordpress, joomla, centos

I cannot install Joomla Component or Wordpress Plugins and also I'm getting a message in Joomla CMS saying it cannot write to the server.

I called hosting company and they said that HTTP write and execute seems disabled.

I'm not sure what owner is created when file or folder is created via script inside CMS. I have seen owner 99 or root before when created via CMS but what effect does that have?

How do I go about changing access rights on which user to ensure this is working?

I'm using Cent OS Linux server.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Comment: What vesion of joomla are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the directory permissions. 
To do that login to admin panel and select "Help > system info" from the top menu. Then select  "Directory permissions" and check if all needed dirs are Writable

Comment: Thank you but how about Wordpress? Is it more with directory permissions aswell?

Comment: Hi, does it helped on Joomla?
If yes, then you should try this on Wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: Hi, the problem here is that I cannot upload Plugin via upload method in Wordpress so I upload to Plugin directory myself but Wordpress doesn't recognise in the CMS. The plugin is uploaded via FTP but not visible in CMS